# gmvault on osx - Received an IMAP abort error. Wait 1 seconds and retrying

Tags: gmail, osx-mavericks

I'm currently trying to backup my gmail using **gmvault**. I have had success with this tool previously. I'm running OSX Mavericks with the latest version of **gmvault** (1.8.1-beta)

After my attempts failed to do a sync I received the following messages:

```
Start emails synchronization.
2000 emails to be fetched.
IMAP (abort) error message = command: FETCH => Gmvault ssl socket error: EOF. Connection lost, reconnect.. traceback:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gmv/imap_utils.pyc", line 117, in wrapper
  File "gmv/imap_utils.pyc", line 504, in fetch
  File "imapclient/imapclient.pyc", line 682, in fetch
  File "imaplib.pyc", line 899, in _command_complete
abort: command: FETCH => Gmvault ssl socket error: EOF. Connection lost, reconnect.

Received an IMAP abort error. Wait 1 seconds and retrying.
Disconnecting from Gmail Server and sleeping ...
logout failed: "<class 'imaplib.abort'>: command: LOGOUT => Gmvault ssl socket error: EOF. Connection lost, reconnect."
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gmv/imap_utils.pyc", line 315, in disconnect
  File "imapclient/imapclient.pyc", line 136, in logout
  File "imapclient/imapclient.pyc", line 775, in _check_resp
error: logout failed: "<class 'imaplib.abort'>: command: LOGOUT => Gmvault ssl socket error: EOF. Connection lost, reconnect."
Reconnecting to the from Gmail Server.
After Enabling compression.
IMAP (abort) error message = command: FETCH => Gmvault ssl socket error: EOF. Connection lost, reconnect.. traceback:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gmv/imap_utils.pyc", line 117, in wrapper
  File "gmv/imap_utils.pyc", line 504, in fetch
  File "imapclient/imapclient.pyc", line 682, in fetch
  File "imaplib.pyc", line 899, in _command_complete
abort: command: FETCH => Gmvault ssl socket error: EOF. Connection lost, reconnect.

Received an IMAP abort error. Wait 2 seconds and retrying.
Disconnecting from Gmail Server and sleeping ...
logout failed: "<class 'imaplib.abort'>: command: LOGOUT => Gmvault ssl socket error: EOF. Connection lost, reconnect."
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gmv/imap_utils.pyc", line 315, in disconnect
  File "imapclient/imapclient.pyc", line 136, in logout
  File "imapclient/imapclient.pyc", line 775, in _check_resp
error: logout failed: "<class 'imaplib.abort'>: command: LOGOUT => Gmvault ssl socket error: EOF. Connection lost, reconnect."
Reconnecting to the from Gmail Server.
```

Answer (score 7):

Turns out in OSX Mavericks you need to change the gmvault configuration file and set `enable_imap_compression` to `false`

```
enable_imap_compression=False
```

More info here:

https://github.com/gaubert/gmvault/issues/154

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs when there is a glitch in your Gmvault configuration file. I have seen in many forums that users face issues with Gmvault. And they also search for Gmvault alternative tools.
I came across many blogs on Gmvault Alternative and I came across this blog on [Gmvault Alternative](http://sysc.org/gmvault-alternative/).

I hope this alternative tool resolves the issue & provides uninterrupted Gmail backup.